# Access a file from the binary table from custom action

Tags: vbscript, wix, windows-installer

I'd like to access a file which is stored in the binary table of a MSI installer from a custom action (VBScript, immediate execution).

My understanding is that the files from the binary table are extracted to some safe location and cleaned up after the installation. So the basic question would probably be: *Can I determine from a custom action the path of this safe location, so that I can access the extracted files?*

I found an alternative approach [here](http://www.itninja.com/question/how-to-call-an-exe-which-is-stored-in-a-binary-table-through-a-vbscript-custom-action-in-the-msi). It reads the database from inside the CA and writes a temporary file itself, but does no cleanup. I have the impression that there must be a better solution.

Comment: I'm a little confused can you elaborate on exactly what you mean by "*so that I can access the extracted files?*". Do you want to run one of the methods in your vbscript as part of the custom action? I don't really understand what you mean by 'access the file' in this context.

Comment: I added another answer to this question for what I think you're trying to do. If it's right just mark it as the answer and I'll deleted my incorrect answer. Or if not a solution you're looking for, clarify in your question or as a comment and I'll try to help you out with what you're trying to do.

Comment: I don't really know how to formulate it better... Let's say I have an executable which is only needed during installation and which I need to call from inside a custom VBScript action. So I place that executable (and its dependencies) in the binary table of the MSI. Now from my custom action (which is a VBScript, type 6, immediate execution during UI sequence) I want to execute that executable.

Comment: The approach I mentioned in my question works basically. It extracts the executable to the temp folder and then executes it (and then does not clean up). But since the installer will extract the binary data to some safe location anyway (and also cleans up), I was wondering if I could access these extracted binary data.

Comment: I understand what you want to do now. Neither of my answers help in this case :)  I'll think about it. It does seem like there should be a way to do this though.

Comment: Thanks for your help Brian. Let me know when you come up with something :)

Comment: I can't think of any already supported mechanism to do what you want to do unfortunately. Adding a cleanup task should be relatively easy at least. Hopefully someone else might come along with a better solution but I can't find one for now. It seems that Windows Installer only ever expects to extract one binary per custom action and you're expected to embed all functionality required into the dll/exe. Managed actions can use the self extracting method to package all dependencies but this is not available to unmanaged/script options.

Comment: Ok thanks for that update. I'll go with the workaround linked in my question for now (and maybe add some cleanup).